# SolrNet faceting asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, solrnet

I'm trying to implement faceting on product catelogue app with Solr, SolrNet and its built with asp.net MCV 3. So far I managed to list all the product results but not the faceting. I could print the facets as shown below.

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var facet in Model.Products.FacetFields["brand"])
    {
      <li>@facet.Key (@facet.Value)</li>
    }
</ul>
```

I have two issues with above code,

1) If the Search results doesn't contain facets for brand its throwing this error
The given key was not present in the dictionary.

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException:
>   The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary. at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary

2) I need to show facets keys and values as links. So on click of that facet I should be able to list the products of the facet.

Here is the schema.xml, please help me if you know the answers for the above questions.

```
<field name="product_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="merchant" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="merchant_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="brand" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="brand_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="categories" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) If the Search results doesn't contain facets for brand its throwing this error The given key was not present in the dictionary.

If you're not doing a [facet field query](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Facets#Querying_by_field) on that field, just don't ask for it in the results.

> 2) I need to show facets keys and values as links. So on click of that facet I should be able to list the products of the facet.

Basically you need to convert the clicked facet value into a [filter query](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Querying#Filter_queries).
There are *many* ways to implement this depending on your specific application needs. See the [SolrNet sample app](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/downloads/list) for one way to do it, use its source code as guidance.

Comment: Hi Maurcio, thanks. -- acctually I've created my project by following the the sample app code. 1) in my controller I have this `AllFacetFields = new[] { "merchant", "brand", "categories"}` . Alos on the sample app all the facets are printed in a one go, but in my case I need to print the facets condinally. Let's say when I list the products I need to show only the facets for `brand`. That's why I didn't use the the way it has done in sample app. As I see I get that error when there is no `brands` on the result set.

Comment: Contd...
2) I tried to print the links like this:

`<ul>
        @foreach (var facet in Model.Products.FacetFields["brand"])
        {
            
            <li>@Url.SetFacet("brand" ,facet.Key) (@facet.Value)</li>
        }
        
        </ul>`

but I get this error: 
`'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' has no applicable method named 'SetFacet' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax`

Comment: ** Update: **
I tried this, it doesn't work as well for issue (1)

`@if (Model.Products.FacetFields["merchant"].Count > 0)
{
        <ul>
        @foreach (var facet in Model.Products.FacetFields["merchant"])
        {
            
            <li>@facet.Key (@facet.Value)</li>
        }
        
        </ul>
}`

Comment: @randika `Url.SetFacet` is an extension method, defined in https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SampleSolrApp/Helpers/UrlHelperFacetExtensions.cs

Comment: @randika: About your other questions, I'm sorry but I won't write your application for you over stackoverflow...

Comment: @randika: to be perfectly honest, it seems you need to develop your .net skills some more first. You're learning too many new things here.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: This is my first time with the SorlNet as well I'm not good in .net too. Anyway thank for your help so far, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Even after adding the facet qury with right parameters, it doesn't work. Can you please give a solution for this [Mauricio Scheffer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/21239/mauricio-scheffer). Many ppl like me are having trouble in faceted search and multifaceting (Seleting multiple values from same category). If you could add some samples, it will be very helpful for us. Thanks!

Comment: @SidharthBalakrishnan: have you seen http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/03/low-level-solrnet.html

Comment: @SidharthBalakrishnan : BTW you didn't answer my questions in your other question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980240/migrating-solrnet-mvc2-application-to-mvc3 I can't help you if you don't give me more information.