# Migrating SolrNet MVC2 Application to MVC3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, solr, solrnet

The  sample application for SolrNET search is in MVC 2. I tried to convert it into MVC 3 application. The search is working perfectly, by connecting to my own solr instance. But the faceting is not getting displayed.

```
private static readonly string[] AllFacetFields = new[] { "Dataaccess", "AccessMethod", "Datacreator", "Dataset", "Geographicalarea"};
```

And when the I sort the search results according to the best match, price and random, I get the link like,

http://localhost:2086/?sort=price

But, what should I do, if I want to change the "price" to something else. I have been working on SolrNet only for the last few days and I'm stuck with the faceting.

Comment: is this about faceting, sorting, or both?

Comment: Need more info: did you change your Solr schema according to the changes you made in the web app? Did you reindex after that?

Comment: @Mauricio: I asked about both faceting and sorting. I changed the schema in the XML files also. (like <field name=....>) Even then its not working. Could it be possibly because of version problem, in ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm on a very tight deadline. Please help

Comment: do you see any results at all? can you facet successfully through the Solr web console?

Comment: Everything works perfectly, except faceting. It worked well for MVC-2, but in MVC-3 only I'm getting problems.

Comment: Yes, using Solr Web console, I'm able to retrieve the values.

Comment: See the generated URL (LoggingConnection outputs this to a file) and compare it to the URL you use in the Solr web console.

Comment: I can see the Get and Post in the LoggingConnection Class. But where should I make changes, 'Cause I couldn't find any URL's in that class.

Comment: No changes to make, just see the log file and compare the generated URL with the one you use in the Solr web console.

Comment: But, where can I find the log file.

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't help me.

Comment: Didn't you find the log? Did you find it but you didn't find the information? Did you find the information but it was OK? Something else? I can't help you if I have to keep guessing...

Comment: I found the solution for this. thanks!

Comment: Say, if I want to get the result of two values from a same category, it doesn't work. It is because, the SetFacet and SetParameters in your application is of IDictionary type and due to the unique key, it doesn't allow. So, the SolrNet really, don't support multifaceting.

Comment: if you found the solution to this question, post it and accept it. About SolrNet supporting multifaceting: **yes it does**, I've been doing it for years. Only the sample app doesn't support it, because it's just a **sample** app, it's not intended to show every feature.

Comment: Don't confuse the library with a sample application.

Comment: Okay, is there any help you could do for that?

Comment: sorry, that's not likely to happen. Implementing every feature in the sample app would take a lot of time, and SolrNet has other priorities, and I have lots of other OSS projects and a lot of paying work. As much as I'd love to live off of my open source projects, it's just not possible right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question title says "Migrating SolrNet MVC2 Application to MVC3" but the real problem of the OP was about implementing multifaceting. The SolrNet sample app doesn't currently implement multifaceting, but [SolrNet itself does](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com.ar/2010/03/low-level-solrnet.html). The OP wanted a sample app with multifaceting for free. See the comments for more information.